# scss file changes not registering

Tags: maven, sass, jhipster, browser-sync

So I have an app that I generated with jhipster and I'm using scss. I've made some changes to an scss file that aren't showing up in my application, even after a 'mvn clean package'. Currently running my application with './mvnw' and 'npm start'

What do I do to make these changes show up in my app?

Comment: Which `.scss` file are you editing? _(vendor, global, ...)_

Comment: I'm editing `my.component.scss`. This component is in my 'home' module

Answer (score 0):

figured it out: `npm run webpack:dev` does the trick